# I can't remove the usb flash-drive safely after succesfully backing up data with acronis true image

Tags: windows-7, backup, usb-flash-drive, acronis-trueimage, safely-remove-hardware

Here's the thing, few weeks ago I had formated my usb flash-drive (slowly) using NTFS and I started backing up data very often with acronis true image 14 succesfully into this flash-drive. After the backups where made the steps I'd do were just closing acronis, press "eject" the flash-drive and once windows would show me the message saying I could remove the unit safely I would do so... so far so good everything was working as expected and I could be sure the data integrity of the disk would be ok.

Now, couple of days ago when Acronis was making a daily backup, my laptop shutdown suddenly because the batery run off (my mistake I would have forgotten to connect it to AC :P). Since that unexpected shutdown, each time I finish of backing up my daily data and I try to eject the usb flash-drive windows7 will show me the next error message (before wouldn't do so):

[image]

So when I try to figure out the reason of this message appearing I just use unlocker on the flash-drive and it's showing me this:

[image]

Finally, to check what this mean i run process explorer and i can see images of the next acronis processes:

[image]

The questions would be:

- Why are these processes still living if I've already closed acronis after the backups have been completed.
- How can I make sure than windows will be able to eject safely my usb flash-drive without killing manually these processes... I'm not fancy of the idea of killing processes without knowing exactly what they're doing behind the curtains (don't want to corrupt data).

Hopefully you guys can advice about this so I can come back to the moment I could have everything working nicely without having to format again my disk nor reinstalling acronis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start by using the error correction tool for that drive.

Comment: @MichaelBay that will not help if Acronis is using/locking the drive.

Comment: doesnt the new acronis come with an option to safely remove your unit after copying? another way would be to stop Acronis, as stated in the existing answer

Comment: Question refers to Acronis True Image 14, also, @elbedoit answer is not referring to the post questions, I'd like to know what those process are doing behind the curtains and whether terminating them manually will corrupt the usb flash-drive

Answer (score 3):

This is because Acronis is still running.

If you look at it on the systray, you can see that it is always running and there is no option to quit if you right click on the icon.

[image: acronis systray icon]
[image: acronis systray right click]

You can also check it in the task manager, you will see something similar to the picture below.
[image: acronis processes]

Because Acronis is using a different approach contrary to what we would expect, there is no way provided by them to gracefully quit the program.

You can use Unlocker to terminate these processes then try to safely remove the Lexar USB drive.